# What does "these" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> They have created traditional works and
>   developed skills that attempt to bring the colors of the moon to
>   life and **many of these** still remains today.

Does "many of these" refer to "traditional works" or "skills"? I think it refers to "traditional works", but I am not sure. Is it context-dependent or is there any other way to figure it out clearly?

Comment: It's ambiguous. It *may* mean one, the other, or both. But there is no *necessity* for it to mean one over the others.

Comment: There are grammatical issues with the sentence outside of the question you've asked. Could you provide the source of the quote and any additional context?

Answer (score 1):

Without additional context I don't know that you could drill down into the exact meaning. It seems like they are grouping the works and the skills together. In which case, both the works and skills still remain today.